# Defining a @classmethod lambda in python

Tags: python, lambda

```
class TestClass(object):
    aa = lambda x: 35
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = self.aa()


o = TestClass()
print o.k
```

This gives me 35, which I understand why.

But this:

```
class TestClass(object):
    @classmethod
    aa = lambda x: 35
    print type(aa)
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = TestClass.aa()


o = TestClass()
print o.k
```

This gives me

```
  File "test1.py", line 3
    aa = lambda x: 35
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why so ?

Answer (score 6):

Decorators are only syntactically valid on `def` and `class` statements.  But the decorator syntax is just shorthand for calling the decorator with the decorated function (or class) as its argument, so you can achieve the same result with:

```
class TestClass(object):
    aa = classmethod(lambda x: 35)
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a decorator on a lambda. You could replace it with

```
aa = classmethod(lambda x:35)
```